# instance.validate() returning true

Tags: grails

Not sure what I am missing here, and I am afraid its something stupid.  Pretty simple setup, I am posting to `/reference/save` and not passing anything... expecting to get back a `required error.`  [Documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html) states that `nullable:true` by default but I am starting to think thats not correct.

```
#domain
class Reference{
    String name;
    String publication;
    String year;
    String section;
    String description;
    String link;
    static constraints = {
        year nullable: true
        section nullable: true
        link url: true
    }   
}

#controller:
Reference referenceInstance = new Reference(params)
println(params)
println(referenceInstance.validate())
```

Output:

```
>>[description:, link:, name:, year:, section:, publication:, action:save, controller:reference]
>>true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the `blank` constraint to your properties.

Your params map contains keys for each property. Grails treat them as empty string, not as `null`.

```
static constraints = {
    year nullable: true
    section nullable: true
    link url: true, blank: false
    description blank: false
    name blank: false
    publication blank: false
}
```